# How to create "Whats this?" style tool tips?

Tags: frontend, ee-1.12

I'm trying to add a tool tip on the checkout pages next to certain fields which users may question the reason why they are required fields, such as phone number.

I want to create a link next to the input box which would show a pop up when clicked. For consistency I want to show it the same as when people click "What's this?" next to the 'Remember Me' check box on the persistent log in template.

```
<a class="link-tip" href="#">What's this?</a>
```

I can't seem to find out how this is called or how to create my own custom one, can anyone help?

Comment: http://www.nickstakenburg.com/projects/prototip2/

Answer (score 3):

You can see how 'remember me' popup is implemented in the file: `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/remember_me_tooltip.phtml`.
This is the function that shows the popup:

```
function toggleRememberMepopup(event){
    if($('remember-me-popup')){
        var viewportHeight = document.viewport.getHeight(),
            docHeight      = $$('body')[0].getHeight(),
            height         = docHeight > viewportHeight ? docHeight : viewportHeight;
        $('remember-me-popup').toggle();
        $('window-overlay').setStyle({ height: height + 'px' }).toggle();
    }
    Event.stop(event);
}
```

And this is the event binding that does it:

```
$$('#remember-me-box a').each(function(element) {
     Event.observe(element, 'click', toggleRememberMepopup);
});
```

The main idea is to put your `<a>` tag inside a container and give it a class (let's say `what-is-this`) and add a js event like this:
$$('.what-is-this a.link-tip').each(function(element) {
    Event.observe(element, 'click', calbackNameHere);
});
Then implemet the function called `callbackNameHere` (feel free to change the name), that looks similar to `toggleRememberMepopup`.

Answer (score 1):

Handled a little bit different in EE I think, managed to find the code where it is created. Hopefully this will help someone else.

When you create the new widget dialog it lets you specify the block-title, block-content and then an optional class to wrap it with as well.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var showTooltip = function() {
this.rememberTip = new Enterprise.Widget.Dialog(
    'What is this?',
    '<p>Checking &quot;Remember Me&quot; will let you access your shopping cart on this computer when you are logged out</p>'+
    '<div class="buttons-set"><button type="button" class="button btn-close"><span><span>Close</span></span></button></div>',
    'popup-remember-tip'
),
$(this.rememberTip.getContent()).select('button.btn-close')[0].onclick = this.rememberTip.hide.bind(this.rememberTip);
this.rememberTip.show();
return false;
}
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
$$('#remember-me-box a').each(function(element) {
    Event.observe(element, 'click', showTooltip);
});
});
//]]>
```

Comment: I would not recommend hardcoded text inside the javascript. A nightmare if you want to change it or translate it or something.